# url codeigniter multilanguage for all pages

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have base url localhost/new/ for multi language website. When changing language language appears in the url localhost/new/en etc. The problem is when I change a page the language disapears localhost/new/popular_tests, when staying on that page I change the language the url goes back to localhost/new/en. The aim is to add language to the certain page like localhost/new/popular_tests/en etc.

I have in controller:

```
public function changeLang($lang_code=''){
            $this->lang->load('main', $lang_code=='' ? 'english' : $lang_code);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('language',$lang_code);

                     redirect(base_url().''.$lang_code);

        }
```

in the config/route.php I have:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['(:any)/test'] = 'home/test/$1';
$route['popular_tests'] = 'home/popular_tests';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;


$route['^(\w{2})/(.*)$'] = '$2';
$route['^(\w{2})$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

Great thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have a `route`defined as `$route['^en$'] = $route['default_controller'];` which means any url ending with `en` will point to `default_controller`.

Try Replacing that route with this:

```
 $route['^new/(:any)/en$'] = 'home/$1';
 $route['(:any)/new/en$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

PS: This is untested version

Comment: Hello, Nishanth Matha, thanks for the response. It didnt work. Now, I have `$route['^(\w{2})/(.*)$'] = '$2';
$route['^(\w{2})$'] = $route['default_controller'];` Can you suggest something wiht this one?

Comment: what was the problem with my earlier solution

Comment: this regex `^(\w{2})$` in `$route['^(\w{2})$'] = $route['default_controller'];` will look for 2 words in route like `en` `am` and will point to `default_controller` so anything like `localhost/en` `localhost/am` `localhost/zz` will be directed to `default_controller`

Comment: try adding this route `$route['new/en/(:any)'] = '$1';`

Answer (score 0):

You should use this one,

```
$route['(\w{2})/test'] = 'home/test';
$route['(\w{2})/(.+)'] = '$2';
$route['(\w{2})'] = $route['default_controller'];
```